# Dozer: get first value on a collection mapped to single value in destination

Tags: java, dozer

I am mapping two DTO objects through Dozer mapper. I am interested in choosing one value from list and map it to a single field in the destination file.

Is it possible to use mapping like this:

```
<field>
   <a>someList[0]</a>
   <b>someVariable</b>
</field>
```

It seems that `b` part can have a `list[1].value` type of approach, but I cannot get it to work when brackets are on `a` side. Where am I making it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need more than suggested

```
<field>
    <a>someList[0]</a>
    <b>someVariable</b>
</field>
```

structure to achieve this. I had the problem other where: I did not call the correct `map()` function for that mapping on my code. I had several mappings and the `map()` call to this specific one was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following mapping:

```
<mapping map-id="collectionMapping" type="one-way">
    <class-a>java.util.Collection</class-a>
    <class-b>java.util.Collection</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>this</a>
        <b set-method="add(java.lang.Object)" type="iterate">anything</b>
        <b-hint>your destination object type</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Why is `a` pointing to `this` and can this be applied to a situation where `b` is eg. a String?

Comment: +1 for a detailed, fast answer. I go still for the simpler solution from the original question. Good to know also that this kind of generic approach is possible.